# consumir Json en android studio FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-13149

Tags: java, android, json, webservice

Tengo el siguiente código para consumir datos desde un webservice:

```
public String enviardatosGet(String user, String pass){

    URL url = null;
    String linea = "";
    int respuesta = 0;
    StringBuilder resul = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://www.nestel.cl/Login.php?user="+user+"&pass="+pass);
        HttpURLConnection conexion= (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        respuesta=conexion.getResponseCode();

        resul=new StringBuilder();

        if (respuesta==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK )
        {
            InputStream in=new BufferedInputStream(conexion.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            while((linea=reader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                resul.append(linea);
            }
        }

        }
    catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return resul.toString();
}


public int obtenerdatosJSON(String response){

    int respuesta = 0;
    try {
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(response);
        if(json.length()>0)
        {
            respuesta = 1;
        }
    }catch (Exception e){}
    return  respuesta;
}


public void onClick(View v) {

    Thread tr = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final String resultado = enviardatosGet(mirut.getText().toString(), mipass.getText().toString());
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int r=obtenerdatosJSON(resultado);
                    if(r>0){
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),menu.class);

                        startActivity(i);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "usuario o pass incorrecto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    tr.start();
}
```

Me arroja el siguiente error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-13149

              Process: com.example.luisalarcon.alumnos, PID: 24002

              java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
                  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
                  at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:627)
                  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:131)
                  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:431)
                  at com.example.luisalarcon.alumnos.MainActivity.enviardatosGet(MainActivity.java:67)
                  at com.example.luisalarcon.alumnos.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:93)
```

¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Quizás puedas ayudar a alguien que intente responder tu pregunta  agregando una pequeña descripción de lo que estás haciendo, marcando cuál es la línea de código que dispara el error, aportando mayor información para que sea más amena la lectura y no haya que revisar todo tu código para entenderlo. Encontrarás el enlace para **[edit]** debajo de tu pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Al dar click en tu boton, no necesitas crear un `Thread`, ya que estas usando **[runOnUiThread()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))**, sugiero agregues dentro también tu petición `enviardatosGet()` ya que de esta forma debe poder ejecutar sin problemas esta operación dentro del Thread principal:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

 //   Thread tr = new Thread(){
 //        @Override
 //       public void run() {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                     String resultado = enviardatosGet(mirut.getText().toString(), mipass.getText().toString());
                    int r=obtenerdatosJSON(resultado);
                    if(r>0){
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),menu.class);

                        startActivity(i);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "usuario o pass incorrecto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
  //      }
  // };
  //  tr.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, el uso de `Threads` en android tiene el incoveniente de que no puedes cambiar nada de la UI desde ahí, puedes usar `AsyncTask` aqui te dejo un ejemplo de como lo podrías montar:

```
private class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
     String resultado = enviardatosGet(mirut.getText().toString(), mipass.getText().toString());
     return resultado;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     int r=obtenerdatosJSON(result);
     if(r>0){
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),menu.class);

        startActivity(i);
     }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "usuario o pass incorrecto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
 }
}

new JsonTask().execute("");
```

No lo he podido probar porque no tengo el Android Studio delante, prueba y me comentas a ver como ha ido.

Un saludo!